# Div блок как ссылка без использовании тега <a>

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать кликабельный `<div>` без использования `<a>`.

Т.е. перехода по ссылке никакой не будет. Нужно исключительно для того, чтобы при клике с помощью JS получить разные данные.

```
<div>
    <div id="id1" class="class1">text1</div>
    <div id="id2" class="class2">text2</div>
    <div id="id3" class="class3">text3</div>
</div>
```

Например, при наведении на  блок с `id1` курсор мыши, как и при наведении на `<a>`, должен стать как при наведении на ссылку(cursor: pointer).

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<div>
    <div id="id1" class="class1" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="alert('hello')">text1</div>
    <div id="id2" class="class2">text2</div>
    <div id="id3" class="class3">text3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ крылся в самом вопросе.

Нужно было в классе добавить:

```
.class1 .class2 . class3{
     cursor: pointer;
 }
```

Всем спасибо!